# Visual Rules in Perseo-CEP

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, complex-event-processing, fiware-perseo

I have been trying to use perseo API with fiware-orion and a question came up:

The Documentation (https://github.com/telefonicaid/perseo-fe/blob/master/documentation/architecture.md) talks about "Visual Rules": JSON rules generated by a portal programatically. This portal is said to be heritage of old DCA.

The thing is that I can't find this portal anywhere and when I click on more info in Doc, it redirects me to a page that needs telefonica ID and Password.

Is this portal open source and implemented?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you said, I'm afraid that portal is part of Telefonica's own product.

best